# Android shared Activities

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, skin

I'm going to create 4 identical apps. The only difference is the icon and my value files Colors.xml, Dimens.xml and Styles.xml, my activities and their layout is the same.

I now have created the first main app, and to make it easier to maintain, I would like to reference the files from the main app in the other apps, and then place a new file of icon, colors.xml aso.. All apps is in the same solutions.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and if I add the files as link in the new project, it fails on calling "Resource.". If I'm creating a reference to the main app, it crash on a "[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]".

Someone who have a nice idea? :)

Answer (score 1):

All that stuff is actually possible to do through the AndroidManifest.xml file. What Xamarin.Android does when annotating the `MainLauncher` `Activity` without specifying the `application` node in the AndroidManifest.xml is to use what you define for the `MainLauncher`.

So instead of having something like:

```
[Activity(Label = "My App Name", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/appIcon")]
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    ...
}
```

move some of that into the manifest:

```
<application android:label="My App" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
```

If you want different icons for your `Activity` and your application, in cases when using `ActionBar`, you can also define `android:logo` in the `application` node of your manifest, pointing it at a `Drawable`.

Comment: Hi, tanks for you replay :) I have updated my question to be bit more clear.